# MySQL syntax error without any invalid token

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

I'm trying to create this procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE RequestApproval (
  IN occupation enum('professor', 'student', 'pastor'),
  IN organization varchar(500),
  IN lastName varchar(100),
  IN firstName varchar(100),
  IN email varchar(300),
  IN phone varchar(50),
  IN description varchar(10000)
)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO `Discounts`(`Occupation`, 
  `Organization`, 
  `LastName`, 
  `FirstName`, 
  `Email`, 
  `Phone`, 
  `Description`) 
VALUES (occupation, 
  organization, 
  lastName, 
  firstName, 
  email, 
  phone, 
  description);
END ;
```

and I'm getting this error

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 24

I don't know what to change when it just says that there is invalid syntax near the empty string (`''`). It won't tell me what the invalid token is--what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need to set an alternate delimiter.  The following will work with the MySQL command line client using the `DELIMITER` keyword, but other clients have their own methods of specifying a delimiter.

```
/* set alternate delimiter $$ */
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE RequestApproval (
  IN occupation enum('professor', 'student', 'pastor'),
  IN organization varchar(500),
  IN lastName varchar(100),
  IN firstName varchar(100),
  IN email varchar(300),
  IN phone varchar(50),
  IN description varchar(10000)
)
BEGIN
/* Use regular delimiter ; in the statement */
INSERT INTO `Discounts`(`Occupation`, `Organization`, `LastName`, `FirstName`, `Email`, `Phone`, `Description`) VALUES (occupation, organization, lastName, firstName, email, phone, description);
/* end the procedure with the alternate delimiter */
END$$
/* reset to ; */
DELIMITER ;
```

It reports a syntax error on line 11 with no specific character, probably because it has interpreted the `;` on that line as the final delimiter ending the procedure (which is invalid without a closing `END`).

Answer (score 1):

try setting the delimiter, with that the end of the procedure will with the DELIMITER and not with `;` look my example I change the insert to make it in my localhost

```
mysql> delimiter \\

jcho360> CREATE PROCEDURE RequestApproval (
    ->   IN occupation enum('professor', 'student', 'pastor'),
    ->   IN organization varchar(500),
    ->   IN lastName varchar(100),
    ->   IN firstName varchar(100),
    ->   IN email varchar(300),
    ->   IN phone varchar(50),
    ->   IN description varchar(10000)
    -> )
    -> BEGIN
    -> INSERT INTO `t1` VALUES (0, lastName, firstName, 0);
    -> END //
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

jcho360> delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If its NOT the delimiter as others have mentioned, and since I don't have MySQL available here, I would hedge to think that it's getting confused with your parameters vs the column names.  You are trying to insert into X ( someColumn ) values ( someColumn )... is it interpreting it the "Values" portion as the column name, or the parameter.

I would try changing the parameters to

```
pOccupation, pOrganization, pLastName, etc...
```

then your insert to be

```
insert into YourTable ( Occupation, Organization, etc... )
   values ( pOccupation, pOrganization, etc... )
```

Then no ambiguity of what MIGHT be taking place under the hood.